# Local MySQL in Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, eclipse, windows, google-app-engine

Is it possible to work with Google App Engine just with local MYSQL and not using Cloud SQL?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager
                 .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=root");
```

the above code gives me error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
```

Answer (score 0):

During development, yes you can.  But you need to configure it in appengine-web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

// Local MySQL instance to use during development.

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root";
```